# What's the difference between the Browser process and Render process in Chromium Embedded Framework?

Tags: chromium-embedded

I've begun reading the documentation for CEF, [on their wiki](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/Home), where there's a frequent referencing to a "Browser process" and a "Render process".

As far as I can tell these two terms are never formally introduced. Is there some other documentation available that describes the purpose of these?

Comment: See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage.md#markdown-header-processes

Comment: CEF has it's own support forum at https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php